# When I assigned a static global pointer, segmentation fault occurred

Tags: c, pointers, makefile, segmentation-fault, malloc

I try to implement a toy malloc,and my code crashed at
`list_head = header`
in

```
#define ADDR_ADD(a, o) (((char*)(a)) + o)
#define HEADER_SIZE (sizeof(heap_header))

static heap_header* list_head = NULL;

int mini_crt_heap_init()
{
        void* base = NULL;
        heap_header* header = NULL;
        unsigned heap_size = 1024 * 1024 * 32;

        base = (void*)brk(0);
        void* end = ADDR_ADD(base, heap_size);
        end = (void*)brk(end);
        if(!end) return 0;

        header = (heap_header*)base;
        header->size = heap_size;
        header->type = HEAP_BLOCK_FREE;
        header->next = NULL;
        header->prev = NULL;

        list_head = header;
        return 1;
}
```

In GDB,the pointer **header** gets the value of the pointer **base**, and I also make some assignments on **header** and they all work. However, when it goes to `list_head = header`,the program crashed.

[The screenshot of gdb: base,end,header and list_head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gncck.png)

My question is that if I can't access the address,it should crash at  `header->size = heap_size;`, which is a normal segfault. But it goes well until `list_head = header;`

I haven't got any idea why segmentation fault occurred, and how can I handle this problem and make it run? Is there any problem with my makefile?

The struct of heap_header:

```
typedef struct _heap_header
{
        enum{
                HEAP_BLOCK_FREE = 0xABABABAB,
                HEAP_BLOCK_USED = 0xCDCDCDCD,
        } type;
        unsigned size;
        struct _heap_header *next;
        struct _heap_header *prev;
}heap_header;
```

My brk():

```
//Linux brk system call
static int brk(void* end_data_segment)
{
        int ret = 0;
        asm("movl $45, %%eax     \n\t"
                "movl %1 , %%ebx \n\t"
                "int $0x80       \n\t"
                "movl %%eax, %0  \n\t"
                : "=m"(ret)
                : "m"(end_data_segment)
                );
        return ret;
}
```

Additional makefile

```
STATIC_SRC = malloc.c stdio.c string.c

STATIC_OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(STATIC_SRC))

CFLAGS =  -c -fno-builtin -nostdlib -fno-stack-protector -m32

static:
        gcc -g $(CFLAGS) $(STATIC_SRC) entry.c
        ar -rs minicrt.a $(STATIC_OBJ)

test:
        gcc -g $(CFLAGS) test.c
        ld -static -melf_i386 -e mini_crt_entry entry.o test.o minicrt.a -o test
all: static test

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.a test core*
```

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Thank you, valgrind tells me (brk segment overflow in thread #1: can't grow to 0xa04d000),but (void*) base and (heap_header*)header both can point to this address, and I can operate (heap_header*)header in my first code.  Everything goes well, except the last assignment    list_header = header   before return 1. Could you give me more advice ?

Comment: Look at the man page for `brk`.  It returns an integer.  That's why you had to cast the result to avoid the compiler warning.  Instead of sweeping it under the rug with a cast, you should have fixed your bug.  As you know from the documentation, on success, `brk` returns zero.  You're trying to use it as a pointer.  So of course you got a segmentation fault.  You're also trying to pass 0 as its argument, rather than the desired pointer value.  Also a bug.  Read the documentation carefully.  Make sure you understand it.  It's generally ill-advised to be using `brk` anyway.  Use `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is my first time to ask questions and I didn't describe my question clearly.I've made some changes. The problem is that I write my own brk(), and it returns an address normally. By the way, I'll try to use malloc when I fix the bug :)

Comment: If it's a user-mode program, then you can't write your own `brk`.  It's a system call.  The OS needs to do it for you.  That's why it's a system call.  Also, why would you use the same name for a function that takes different arguments and has a different return value?

Comment: "Static global" is like saying "indoors pool for outdoors use", it doesn't make sense. Either something is "global" and then it has external linkage (available through `extern`) or something is "static" and then it has internal linkage. It can't have both at once. Not to be confused with scope. A variable may be declared at _file scope_ with internal linkage as in this case - that's not a "global".

Comment: @TomKarzes I'm reading an extremely old book published in 2009. Maybe it's not suitable for learning now.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks. I didn't realize the mistake and I have a better understanding now.

Comment: "*An extremely old book published in 2009*" -- LOL. I've got underwear older than that, not to mention books.  Just the other day I was referring to my copy of the 1st edition of K&R, copyright 1978.  I've no idea what book *you're* looking at, but if it's advising you to write your own user-mode `brk()` function, especially one with a different signature than the standard one, then it's simply a bad book.  You should find a better one.  It's not a matter of the book being out of date.

Comment: @JohnBollinger K&R contains an example of how to write your own function `sbrk`. The code they used was, as far as I remember, a veritable orgy in bad programming practices.

Comment: @Lundin, K&R does present `alloc()` and `free()` examples for didactic purposes, but I don't find `brk()` or `sbrk()`, and it certainly does not advise users that writing their own of any of these for userspace use is something they should actually do.  Nor did I claim that any of the code examples in that book are appropriate models for modern C.  The point is that a 2009 book might be dated, but it is not "extremely old", and considerably older books still have useful things to offer, even if not example code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger hahaha,  my real meaning is "extremely" old, my bad. I thought people just do not program in this way. Maybe "out of date" is much proper than "'extremely' old".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I remembered wrong, it was `malloc` that they were teaching how to (not) implement, chapter 8.7 (2nd ed).